# Using custom hooks in non functional component in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am trying to access my own custom hook in a simple non functional component. I want to add Authorization header in axios for every request. This is what I am trying:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useStore } from '../Store/store';

const instance = axios.create({
   baseURL: 'http://apiurl.is.here/api/'
});

instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = useStore()[0].token;
export default instance;
```

Now I know that custom hooks (useStore in this case) can only be used in functional components. How I can use my custom hook and get state in non functional component?

I am getting this error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. **You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks**. Yes I am :(
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

**EDIT**
My Store:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

let globalState = {};
let listeners = [];
let actions = {}

export const useStore = (shouldListen = true) => {

const setState = useState(globalState)[1];

const dispatch = (actionIdentifier, payload) => {
    const newState = actions[actionIdentifier](globalState, payload);
    globalState = { ...globalState, ...newState };

    for (const listener of listeners) {
        listener(globalState);
    }
}


useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldListen) {
        listeners.push(setState);
    }
    return () => {
        if (shouldListen) {
            listeners = listeners.filter(li => li !== setState);
        }
    }
}, [setState, shouldListen]);

 return [globalState, dispatch];

}


export const initStore = (userActions, initialState) => {
if (initialState) {
    globalState = {...globalState, ...initialState}
}

 actions = {...actions, ...userActions};
}
```

Comment: If you know hooks can only be used in functional components then why would you ask how you can use them in non-functional components? What sort of "store" are you trying to get access to? A redux store [getState](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate)?

Comment: You answered the question yourself - you can't.

Comment: @DrewReese Ok! Make it simple! Is there anyway to set common auth header which is save in state?

Comment: What does your store look like?

Comment: @JohnRuddell See my edit

Comment: You can use hooks in functional components and (with a hack) in class components.
If you want to use the hook in class component, please show the class component.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher why dont you make an actual storage class with an instance that you can access outside of any component? Instead of a `globalState` variable that you update inside your hook. Then you can use it when setting up axios.

Comment: Making requests may not always want a token, you may want to consider making an api class that attaches the token to `authenticated` requests. This way you can distinguish between when you want to actually send the token or not. (like a login call for instance wouldn't have a token).